# Need help getting column stacked links to flex into a row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a button and a link aligned to column with flexbox.  I want to change just the link and button to fit onto one row at max-width: 800px;  I have searched for and found no answer that fits exactly what I need.  Hope someone can help and it is probably an easy fix but I can't seem to figure it out.

Here is my CSS & HTML:

```css
.landing {
  position: relative;
}
#pic {
  display: flex;
}
#pic figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.5em;
  font-size: 7vw;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  color: #ffff66;
}
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .buttonWrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
/*****Signup button*****/

.home-signup {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  border: 2px solid #ffff66;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #ffff66;
  padding: 0.5em 2.5em;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
/****login button****/

.home-login {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 1.8em;
  color: #ffff66;
  top: 72%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<section class="landing">
  <figure id="pic">
    <img srcset="images/detail/landingBig.jpg 1920w,
                  images/detail/landingMedium.jpg 960w,
                  images/detail/landingSmall.jpg 480w" sizes="100vw" src="images/detail/landingMedium.jpg" alt="Top Banner with pic of two speakers on a wooden floor">
    <figcaption>Collabo</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <div class="buttonWrapper">
    <button class="home-signup">Signup</button>
    <a class="home-login" href="#">Login</a> 
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Adding `white-space: nowrap` to your media query `.buttonWrapper` should work

Comment: adding the white-space: nowrap didn't work.  It still stays in a column.

Comment: Yeah, see that now ... missed all your `position: absolute` ... remove them and redesign your layout.

Comment: I suggest you add an image how you want it to look like, as of now, one can't really see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do  a reset on a few rules and write or load mediaqueries last:

```
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .buttonWrapper {
    display: flex;
    border: solid;
    flex-direction: row;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
  }
  .home-signup,
  .home-login {
    transform: scale(1);
    margin: 1em;
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```css
.landing {
      position: relative;
    }
    #pic {
      display: flex;
    }
    #pic figcaption {
      position: absolute;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      letter-spacing: 0.5em;
      font-size: 7vw;
      z-index: 1;
      top: 30%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
      color: #ffff66;
    }

    /*****Signup button*****/

    .home-signup {
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 2.5vw;
      border: 2px solid #ffff66;
      border-radius: 10px;
      color: #ffff66;
      padding: 0.5em 2.5em;
      top: 60%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      background: none;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    /****login button****/

    .home-login {
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 1.8em;
      color: #ffff66;
      top: 72%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      cursor: pointer;
    }

 @media (max-width: 800px) {
  .buttonWrapper {
    display: flex;
    border: solid;
    flex-direction: row;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
  }
  .home-signup,
  .home-login {
    transform: scale(1);
    margin: 1em;
    position: static;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="landing">
      <figure id="pic">
        <img  src="http://lorempixel.com/800/600" alt="Top Banner with pic of two speakers on a wooden floor">
        <figcaption>Collabo</figcaption>
      </figure>
      <div class="buttonWrapper">
        <button class="home-signup">Signup</button>
        <a class="home-login" href="#">Login</a> 
      </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: This worked to get them into a row.  .home-signup is for some reason partially outside the .buttonwrapper.  Any idea why that is?

Comment: @thomasna82 the media querie should be set last in the style sheet., I made a snippet up here in the answer